# How to insert dummpy map values in pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hdfs

I am doing a conditional check for null and empty occurrence of a bag. The contains multiple map arrays. Whenever 'info' is null or empty I want to put a dummy map values into this. Because in the next step I am doing a FLATTEN operation on 'info'.

Why I need this because null or empty bag in FLATTEN will remove the complete record from the data which I don't want.

```
((info is null or IsEmpty(info)) ? {(['Unknown'#'unknown'])} : info) as info;
```

This is giving me below compilation error?

2014-09-02 06:20:37,978 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered "  ": "" at line 24, column 70.
Was expecting one of:
     
    "cat" ...
    "clear" ...
    "fs" ...
    "sh" ...
    "cd" ...
    "cp" ...
    "copyFromLocal" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a syntax error while creating a map. There is an easy way to create map using [TOMAP](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/TOMAP.html) function, which you can use as below:

```
((info is null or IsEmpty(info)) ? {(TOMAP('Unknown','unknown'))} : info) as info;
```